# Upload a textfile using script in Google spreadsheets and write the contents of the textfile into a sheet in the spreadsheet

Tags: upload, google-apps-script, text-files, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

Using a custom function that is called by clicking a button on Google Spreadsheets, I want to upload a text file into a specific folder and then put the contents into a specific sheet of the spreadsheet?

I know how to create a button and call a custom function on clicking it. Now through my custom function I want to:

1. Ask the user to browse to the text file location, and then select the file and upload it.
2. Upload it to a specific location and also change the file name to a specific name I want.
3. Read the contents of the text file and put them into a sheet in the spreadsheet.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Creating a button, and assigning a macro (function) to that button, or you could just as easily create a new menu item in your Google spreadsheet. The new menu item would be achieved programmatically using a custom function, and executed using the onOpen trigger for your spreadsheet.

```js
 function onOpen(){
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var menuEntries = [ {name: "Text File Upload", functionName: "text_file_upload"},
                        {name: "Change Name", functionName: "change_name"},
                        {name: "TextFile to S.sheet", functionName: "t_file_ssheet"} ];
    ss.addMenu("Text Files", menuEntries);
 } //this onOpen function will add a new menu to your spreadsheet called "Text Files" with 3 submenu items you can use to work with your text files.

 function text_file_upload() {
    Browser.msgBox("You are about to upload new text file");
  //insert code here to get textfile location/Url and  Textfile Data, this can be stored in array 
 }

 function change_name() {
    var newName = Browser.inputBox("Enter the new name for the text file:");
  //insert code here to assign new file name to the text file
 }

 function t_file_ssheet(){
    //insert code here to copy data from your textfile to a sheet in your spreadsheet
 }
```

There is a very nice tutorial here [Tutorial: Interacting With Your Docs List](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/docslist_tutorial?hl=en/%22have%20a%20look%20at%20this%20tutorial%22) that covers most of the coding your looking for.